# Express Rendering Array Object is Undefined in EJS; Asynchronous Issue

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
    router.get('/getChefMeals/:uid', function(req, res, next) {
    var userid = req.params.uid;
    var allMealsIds = [];
    var allMeals = [];

    console.log("inside the getChefMeals/UID");
    console.log("the uid is " + userid);

    db.ref("chefs/" + userid).child("meals").once("value",function(dataSnapShot){
        dataSnapShot.forEach(function(snap){
            allMealsIds.push(snap.getKey());
        });
        allMealsIds.forEach(function(obj){
            console.log("obj should be key of meals " + obj);
            db.ref("meals/" + obj).once("value",function(dataSnapShot){
                // console.log("dataSnapShot is " + dataSnapShot);
                console.log("dataSnapShot key is " + dataSnapShot.getKey());
                console.log("value is " + dataSnapShot.val());
                allMeals.push({meal: dataSnapShot.val(), key: dataSnapShot.getKey()});
            });
        });
        console.log("Outside allmealsloop length",allMeals.length);
        res.render("detail_chef.ejs",{chefMeals: allMeals});    
    });
});
```

In the above code block, I'm trying to `res.render` the `allMeals` object which is an array of JSON objects directly to the `ejs` file in `detail_chef`. However, in the `ejs` file, it is undefined.

The `console.log` shows that due to asynchronous nature of express routers, `console.log("Outside allmealsloop length",allMeals.length);` from the second last line returns a length of 0.

The Firebase DB `console.log` returns all the data just fine and the `allMeals` is an array with the correct length.

I just want to know how I can pass this array `allMeals` to the `ejs`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting meals one by one you should get all meals in one query like $in concept and after getting all the meals send the response from it's callback.

If you have to follow the same approach as you are doing it right now then either you can use recursion or you can check the allMeals length and allMealIds length when they are equal send them to ejs.

```
 router.get('/getChefMeals/:uid', function(req, res, next) {
    var userid = req.params.uid;
    var allMealsIds = [];
    var allMeals = [];

    console.log("inside the getChefMeals/UID");
    console.log("the uid is " + userid);



   db.ref("chefs/" + userid).child("meals").once("value",function(dataSnapShot){
        dataSnapShot.forEach(function(snap){
            allMealsIds.push(snap.getKey());
        });
        allMealsIds.forEach(function(obj){
            console.log("obj should be key of meals " + obj);
            db.ref("meals/" + obj).once("value",function(dataSnapShot){
                // console.log("dataSnapShot is " + dataSnapShot);
                console.log("dataSnapShot key is " + dataSnapShot.getKey());
                console.log("value is " + dataSnapShot.val());
                allMeals.push({meal: dataSnapShot.val(), key: dataSnapShot.getKey()});
if(allMeals.length === allMealIds.length){
        res.render("detail_chef.ejs",{chefMeals: allMeals});    

}
            });
        });
        console.log("Outside allmealsloop length",allMeals.length);
    });
});
```

but I will recommend you to get all the meals using one query.